# Как использовать UIActivityViewController в UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, xcode

Никак не могу понять, как использовать UIActivityViewController в классе ячеек, в простом контроллере все работает.
Подскажите что я упустил в коде.

```
class friendCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var add: Bool = true

    @IBOutlet weak var likeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var friendImage: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
            self.likeLabel.text = "567"
    }

    @IBAction func share(_ sender: Any) {
        let items = [friendImage.image]
        let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items as [Any], applicationActivities: nil)
        present(ac, animated: true) -- вот этой функции нет в ячейке, чем заменить?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел вот такую функцию:

```
func topViewController()-> UIViewController{
        var topViewController:UIViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!

        while ((topViewController.presentedViewController) != nil) {
            topViewController = topViewController.presentedViewController!;
        }

        return topViewController
    }
```

И вот так используем

```
topViewController().present(ac, animated: true)
```